# Update state array by object Id

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update state array object by particular id.

Suppose I have following object in state. And I tried to  update by following way using id but, it doesn't  work for me.

It didn't update state data.

```js
this.state = {
      data: [{id:'124',name:'qqq'}, 
           {id:'589',name:'www'}, 
           {id:'45',name:'eee'},
           {id:'567',name:'rrr'}]
}

publishCurrentProject = user => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
        data: prevState.data.map(item =>
          item.id === user.id ? { ...user } : item
        ),
  }))
}

let user = {id:'124',name:'ttt'};

publishCurrentProject(user);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What doesn't work? What's happening instead? How and where are you using this code? Please include a [mcve].

Comment: @EmileBergeron It didn't update state data.

Comment: How did you confirm that the state wasn't updated?

Comment: I checked state data after few seconds.

Comment: Again, please include a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're saying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the problem is on how you called the `publishCurrentProject()`, maybe you put that function in the wrong context. I use your implementation and it still works

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      data: [
        { id: "124", name: "qqq" },
        { id: "589", name: "www" },
        { id: "45", name: "eee" },
        { id: "567", name: "rrr" }
      ]
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.publishCurrentProject = this.publishCurrentProject.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e) {
    let user = { id: "124", name: "ttt" };

    this.publishCurrentProject(user);
  }

  publishCurrentProject(user) {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      data: prevState.data.map((item) =>
        item.id === user.id ? { ...user } : item
      )
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Test</h1>
        {this.state.data.map((el) => (
          <p>{el.name}</p>
        ))}
        <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Change</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Codesandbox for worked example

[image: Edit late-dew-6e6ky]

Comment: `publishCurrentProject` is an arrow function class property, so it has the component's context automatically without needing to use `bind` or other trickery.